# How to set continous kafka consumer in php ,with out connection time out

Tags: php, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am using the following code to read message from kafka . But to set consumer i have to give connection timeout . In my case i want a continuous reading consumer i cant set connection time out because some time it may not get any message from long time .  How i handle it .

```
while (true) { 
    $message = $topic->consume(0, 1200);  //120*10000);
    if(isset($message->err)){
        switch ($message->err) {
            case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR:
            break;
            case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__TIMED_OUT
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }

}
```